# Broken Images and Pages Do Not Load

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection, website

I am using Chrome and get broken images. I also get "This Page is Not Available". Afrer refreshing I see "Resolving..." in status bar but page fails to load. Refreshing several seconds later brings up the page but when clicking on links further, it depends but page either loads or not.

I have found that my LAN was disconnecting and reconnecting so I changed the placing of cable to another router's slot. Seems like it's working better now and here is what I found in router's logs:

```
Aug 25 02:08:22 (none) user.notice syslog: Note: adding MFC: 192.168.2.101 -> 234.55.66.77, InpVIf: 1
Aug 25 02:12:55 (none) user.notice syslog: Note: removing MFC: 0.0.0.0 -> 234.55.66.77, InpVIf: 1
```

I don't know if it means something but I was hoping to find some clue as why it was disconnecting and reconnecting.